# Installing skype on Linux Mint/Debian

Tags: skype

I am trying to install Skype using [skype](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=dynamic) tar package from the dynamic option on [skype download page](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/).

I moved the `skype` binary to `/usr/bin` and rest files to `/usr/share/skype` as per the readme.

I am still unable to start skype using command on terminal

```
skype
```

or in `/usr/bin`:

```
cd /usr/bin
./skype
```

How can I install Skype?

Comment: Why aren't you using the deb version of skype package?

Comment: @Lizardx i was hoping that i could avoid i386 libraries.. but turns out I can't

Answer (score 2):

**On Mint** from repository:
`apt-get install skype`

**On Debian** Jessie:
`dpkg --add-architecture i386`
`aptitude update`

```
aptitude install libc6:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxss1:i386 libxv1:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
```

`wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb`
`dpkg -i skype-install.deb`